# How to merge all <td> with class

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

How to merge all `<td>` with class in Javascript/CSS. I don't want to put the class on `<tr>`. The class is on specific `<td>`.

```
<table class="mytables">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Header col 1 </th>
            <th> Header col 2 </th>
            <th> Header col 3 </th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col_span"> A </th>
            <td class="col_span"> </th>
            <td> B </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> C </th>
            <td> D </th>
            <td> E </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> F </th>
            <td> G </th>
            <td> H </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result will be like this.

[image]

I know about colspan, and it is not what I need.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "join"? Please edit your question to describe in more detail what you've tried and what result you want.

Comment: define `join` in your perspective

Comment: what I mean in join is merge ^_^

Comment: I didn't understand, what do you want?

Comment: answered by @sushmit.patil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to merge td with col_span `class`.

```js
$(function(){
 $("tr").each(function(){
  var empty = $(".col_span:empty",$(this)).length;
  $notEmpty = $(this).find(".col_span").not(":empty");
  $notEmpty.attr("colspan",empty+1);
  $(".col_span:empty",$(this)).remove();
 });
});
```

```html
<table class="mytables">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th> header col 1 </th>
    <th> header col 2 </th>
    <th> header col 3 </th>
   </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr> 
    <td class="col_span"> A </td>
    <td class="col_span"></td>
    <td> B </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> C </th>
    <td> D </th>
    <td> E </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> F </th>
    <td> G </th>
    <td> H </th>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a style to all `<td>` elements, you could add this code to the `<head>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    td{
    /* CSS Properties Here */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Yes ^_ I know that. What I don't know is how to merge those `<td>`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by merge?

Answer (score 0):

With a pure js it will look like:

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
for(var i = 0; i< tds.length; i++)
{
    tds[i].className += 'yourClassName';
}
```

With jQuery:

```
$('td').addClass('yourClassName');
```